# Show that G', the commutator subgroup of G, is normal in G. Prove that any subgroup A with G' $\subseteq$ A $\subseteq$ G is normal in G.

Tags: finite-groups

Show that G', the commutator subgroup of G, is normal in G.
Prove that any subgroup A with G' $\subseteq$ A $\subseteq$ G is normal in G.

So the definition of the commutator subgroup is that;

In the group G, let G' be the subgroup generated  by the set {$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ : x,y in G}.

So to show it is normal in G I must show that ($xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^{-1}G'xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$=G' but I just can't manipulate it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $g \in A$.  You know that $k= hgh^{-1}g^{-1} \in A$, because $k= hgh^{-1}g^{-1} \in G' \subset A$.  Hence $hgh^{-1} = kg \in A$.

Note that this proof is shorter than the standard proof that $G'$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: would it be possible to explain how I would continue on from $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^{-1}G'(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=G'$ so i can get a better understanding?

Comment: I don't see how this would even help.

Comment: that's proving it is normal is it not?

Comment: No.  To prove $A$ is normal you need to show that if $g \in A$, and $h \in G$, then $hgh^{-1} \in A$.

Comment: The first part of the question is: Show that G', the commutator subgroup of G, is normal in G.

Comment: but a subset X is normal if $g^{-1}Xg=X$ so why can't I just prove that?

Comment: To do the first part of the question, you need to prove that if $g \in G'$, and $h \in G$, then $hgh^{-1} \in G'$.  You can get that from my answer by setting $A = G'$.  (I'm sure the person who made the question meant for you to go via the method proposed by @Sam.)

Comment: A subset is normal if $h^{-1} X h = X$, for all $h \in G$.  That's what I did.

Comment: I don't understand how you have shown that $h^{-1}Xh=X$

Comment: I showed that $h^{-1} X h \subset X$.  To finish off the proof, you note that $h X h^{-1} \subset X$, because $h^{-1} \in G$.  Hence $X \subset h^{-1} X h$.

Comment: i really don't understand how you have shown it thoguh

Comment: I think you need to review the definitions, and check through them carefully.

Comment: I follow that if g in G and k=$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ then k in G since k in G' and G' $\subset$ G. Thus $xyx^{-1}=ky$ in G but then I don't see how you can then say $xyx^{-1} \subset G$ or anything from that point.

Comment: Look up the definition of what it means for $A \subset B$.

Comment: oh ok, i think I've got it, but what about after that part.

Answer (score 0):

A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is normal if $gng^{-1}$ is in $N$ for all $g\in G$ and $n\in N$. You can use this to check normality of the derived subgroup.